# Bypass packets from kernel space to user space

Tags: linux-kernel, netfilter

I am trying to simulate a tcp accleration algorithm on a linux machine. From what i understand i have to bypass the kernel network stack and relay the incomming packets to my custom code. I am currently looking at netfilter hooks to intercept the packets, but i dont understand how to pass packet to user space yet. can you help?

Comment: Welcome to SO - that magic place where people just write the code for you.  Suggest you take a look at how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at [PACKET_MMAP](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt) facility which is available in Linux kernel and allows for packet reception built on a circular buffer ring mapped to user space. The document at the link is some sort of exhaustive, and also various examples exist such as *libpcap*.